# Azure Biztalk calling Bridge as One Way External Service Endpoint

Tags: wcf, authentication, azure, biztalk

I am trying to call an existing bridge from Azure BizTalk Service, but getting following error:

Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'domain-name'.

I have tried all possible configurations of WCF bindings but none of them work, the last configuration is as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceCredentialBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="CN=certificate-name"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <clear />
      <endpoint address="https://bridge-url" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.ISimplexDatagramRouter" name="OneWayExternalServiceEndpointReference2" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceCredentialBehavior">
        <identity>
          <certificate encodedValue="encoded-value" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Could you please advise if I am missing something very obvious, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your certificate self signed ? if yes then you must :

- Create a self-signed certificate to be used to encrypt an SSL channel
- Upload a certificate to Windows Azure using the Windows Azure Management portal
- Enable an HTTPS endpoint on a Windows Azure web role
  All detailed instructions are available here 
  [How To: Enable SSL with a Self-Signed Certificate on Windows Azure][1]

If your certificated is not self signed then I Think you must add the certificate to your local root certificate authority

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry a bit late in responsd. I have managed to solved the problem by using EAI bridge and using bridge chaining, here is the example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BizTalk-Bridge-chaining-2246b104